# POST https://kovan.infura.io/MG.......... 405 () + Uncaught Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: "" with web3js and metamask

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, metamask, infura

I am trying to make a website that lets someone interact with my contract(deployed through remix using metamask onto kovan) but I am getting the above error when I try a signed function. All unsigned functions work perfectly.

One problem I think is this section of code:

```
web3.eth.getAccounts(function (error, accounts) {
  if (error) return console.error(error)
  console.log(accounts)
})
```

On my website it gives an empty array, but on https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KoRWyZ it returns["0x92165d2b80974733b7115e3cbf8285e70132d9e9"].

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  //web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://kovan.infura.io/MGb05nymXluRaB7138hk"));
} else {
  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://kovan.infura.io/MGb05nymXluRaB7138hk"));
}
web3.eth.getBlock(48, function(error, result){
    if(!error)
        console.log(result)
    else
        console.error(error);
})
web3.eth.getAccounts(function (error, accounts) {
  if (error) return console.error(error)
  console.log(accounts)
})

web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
var MContract = web3.eth.contract([ABI]);
var ContractIst = papyrContract.at('address');
console.log(ContractIst);
```

When I try to run a signed function on the contractInst I get the above error. I have tried using both wamp and heliohost(http) but neither work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting your between this:

```
// Wait for loading completion to avoid race conditions with web3 
injection timing.
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    //Your code here..

});
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to update web3.js to beta 33 and use this but it eventually worked.